# Django middleware autocommit cannot be used

Tags: python, django, postgresql, transactions

Our code has custom middleware to record requests and responses so we can log API activity.

```
def process_response(self, request, response):
    user = None
    try:
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            user = request.user
        the_record = Record(
            requestUser=user,
            requestPath=request.path,
            requestMethod=request.method)
        the_record.save()
    except:
        pass
```

In process_response method, we create object and save it. If API method is marked with `@transaction.atomic`, log message `autocommit cannot be used inside a transaction` will appear.

No exception in method, but simply record in database in that case for that specific API call does not exist.

Is there any explanation why autocommit log message appears? Maybe to use model manager `create` instead of `save` method?

Comment: Please, don't ever ever do `except: pass`.

Comment: Noted, ignore it here please, this is example, I am not allowed to pass real code.

Comment: Are you by chance using `postgrespool` (https://github.com/kennethreitz/django-postgrespool/issues/24)?

Comment: Nothing, just clean django. I think it is related to save and because it is making its own transaction, but I am still not sure why exception happens there. Documentation is not having anything similar